# How does Google Maps know the location names?

Tags: google-maps, data

How does Google Maps know the name of the very small shop in my street? How do they collect that kind of data?

Comment: There are a few ways. Users/business can submit this information. Also, since Google is a search engine, it would be easy for them to use their own search results to update their information.

Comment: They also have teams of data entry people working on tasks... i know from experience ^^

Comment: Google Maps credits one of its major sources as The Yellow Pages, Inc. Although this might be a source it used in its early years. It also lists TomTom as a source of information.

Answer (score 1):

In Turkey, their data provider is Basarsoft.

Basarsoft is a mapping company which has been in business for more than 15 years. They have field teams all over Turkey, patrolling with their cars and bikes and recording every street name, points of interest (such as parks, hospitals, stores, malls etc.) and boundaries aswell.

This dataset is refreshed almost every 6 months. Metropolitan areas have shorter update intervals such as 3 months.

Although google wants people to provide this info, their major providers are companies all over the world such as Basarsoft.